# Assign three key combination in any one of keys

Tags: autohotkey

how can i assign Control + Shift + S in any of one of the keys like,ALT or 4 or space using autohotkey.I am new to autohotkey. I need this key combination in a single key. since, in my work i need to press these keys repeatedly?

Answer (score 2):

space::^+s

Replace space with the key you want to be remaped into Control + Shift + S.